# Linux Sort Command prevent waiting

Tags: python, linux, sorting

Is it possible to prevent `sort` command from waiting?  I was assuming that sort will continue sorting even if one of the inputs is/are waiting.  As long as the other one waiting is still higher than the other ones.

For example, lets say we have 2 following python scripts:

test1.py:

```
import time

print("100 |test1_1", flush=True)
print("105 |test1_2", flush=True)
print("110 |test1_3", flush=True)
time.sleep(5)
print("111 |test1_4", flush=True)
```

test2.py:

```
import time

print("102 |test2_1", flush=True)
print("103 |test2_2", flush=True)
print("104 |test2_3", flush=True)
print("105 |test2_4", flush=True)
print("106 |test2_5", flush=True)
print("107 |test2_6", flush=True)
print("108 |test2_7", flush=True)
print("109 |test2_8", flush=True)
```

When I do `sort -mk1 <(python test1.py) <(python test2.py)` I dont seem to get any results until the entire thing is done.

Is sort just not printing/flushing the sorted results right away to the console?  Not sure if this is the case, since even if I print a lot more data, it still wont print anything until the entire thing is complete.  If it needs to hit a buffer size first before printing in the console, is there a way to flush the results out in console right away?  Or is it just waiting for the entire inputs to be completed before it does any sorting.

I was assuming when I run the command, I will see the following right away

```
100 |test1_1
102 |test2_1
103 |test2_2
104 |test2_3
105 |test1_2
105 |test2_4
106 |test2_5
107 |test2_6
108 |test2_7
109 |test2_8
110 |test1_3
```

wait/sleep, then print the remaining.

```
111 |test1_4
```

Unfortunately, I dont see anything until the sleep is completed, then the entire results is printed out.

Comment: How could it possibly output anything before the input is completely received???  How would it know that no future input items will be less than the lowest seen so far, and therefore would have to be output first?

Comment: The `<(python test1.py)` constructs, seen through the eyes of the `sort` utility, are just a file handle. You basically told `sort` to scan through 2 files and reorder the lines, and `sort` goes through that by opening file1, reading until it hits EOF, then starting on file2 and so on.

Comment: I was assuming with the `-m` or merge option, it will just read, for this example, just 2 inputs (one line from each) and compare each.  The one that is lower will be printed, then it will iterate for the next line for that specific file handle

Comment: Clearly then that assumption was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The `sort` command will indeed write all sorted lines to the output, once it has sorted them. However, `sort` cannot see into the future and tell if the next line to be read is before any of the lines it already has read.

So, `sort` will only start sorting once it has consumed all its input, as it cannot start sorting until it has all the data it needs to sort.

Basically, `sort` is a batch-type algorithm, not an online-type algorithm.